# 301 redirect, keyword being in bold

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, 301-redirect, keywords

Regarding 301; If I redirect no-www to www domain with 301 redirect, do I still have to determinate inside Google webmaster tools which version (www or nonwww) is prefered? Or is setting up redirect enough so therefore I don't need to determinate that inside GWT?

Regarding keyword being in bold: Usually keywords are supposed to be in bold font and it is irrelevant if they are links or not. But in heading (h1, h2); does there keyword also need to be in bold or is it enough if I care to put it to the beginning of heading? So else how asked; Does the keyword in heading need to be in bold font also?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should specify your preference in GWT, too, so it's both clear and consistent for Google. Redundancy is better then hoping it works.
2. Text in headers is usually in bold by default but it's not the appearance of the text that gives it SEO value. It's the semantic value of the heading tags that gives it value. A heading tag can be styled to not appear bold but it still keeps its value for SEO. (Don't style headings to look like normal text, though. That *may* get you flagged during a manual review if one should happen to be done for your site).
3. **bonus answer** text in a `<b>` and `<strong>` tags do have a a little more SEO value then words not in those tags but it almost certainly isn't a big help. If you put all of the keywords you want to rank well for in bold your site will look silly. That won't help you retain visitor or attract links. Both are needed to have a successful website.

Comment: I'd disagree with #1. If you redirect from www to non-www, Google will never display the www version is search results. In GWT you would also need to add both domains in order to set one as the default. IMO this is all completely unnecessary.